# Processing mysql records in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table with scores that contestants get after the complete a quiz. I then select the `max(points)` for each user and i group by user

```
select distinct userName, max(points) as numpoints
from tblscore
group by userName 
order by numpoints desc
```

this gives me the order of all the highest scores for the user. i want to store these records in an array and process it, i want to rank each record plus i want to display records where the users have a tie. How can this be achieved? how will the array be set up and processed to cater for this.

Comment: you are using jdbc, and you are aware of result sets and statements, right?

Comment: yes i am using jdbc and yep i am using a result set

Comment: and what do you want your array to look like? Array of what?

Comment: the array will hold the same information selected in the select statement i want to then use the index of the array to get the rank of the user for that quizz and i also want to cater for users that have the same score and display it as a tie

Comment: Please address the issues one at a time and show some working code for each question. We're there to assist you in letting you write the code, not writing the entire program for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a class (e.g. `UserScore`) with two fields - `username` and `points`
2. Get the `ResultSet` for the desired query (via a `Statement`)
3. Define a `List<UserScore> list = new ArrayList<UserScore>`
4. Loop the result set, using `while (rs.next())` and on each iteration create a new instance of the `UserScore` class, set both of its fields (e.g. `userScore.setPoints(rs.getInt("numpoints")`), and then add the object to the `list`
5. If you can do with a `List` - go with it. If you really need an array - use `list.toArray(..)`

---

Alternatively, you can use apache [commons-dbutils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/), and after you create the `UserScore` class, you just call:

```
List<UserScore> list = new BeanListHandler(UserScore.class).handle(resultSet);
```

Note that in this case your fields should be called the same way as your returned column names/aliases. You can also use the `ArrayListHandler`, which, instead of a list of the defined class, will give you a `List<Object[]>` where each column will be an element in the array.

Comment: ok i did that i now have a list of type UserScores i can now print the list of scores for the user but how can i manipulate the list so that i can say which users have tied

Comment: iterate it and see if two adjacent users have the same score.

Comment: yes i am able to see two users with the same score. how can i manipulate this to say that the users with the same score have a tie?

Comment: well that depends entirely on how you want to display it. It is not a manipulation, it's a display issue.

Comment: any suggestions on how i can do this?